# No guarda ni busca datos en el archivo.dat C++

Tags: c++

El problema mas detallado es que cuando ingreso un nuevo alumno lo guarda, lo busco y lo muestra, pero a partir de que ingreso el segundo alumno en adelante me tira "Error: DNI Incorrecto. Toque cualquier botón para volver al menú anterior". No se si guarda un solo alumno o cuando busco el segundo en adelante no busca. Dejo abajo código donde ingreso alumno y busco alumnos

```
struct Alumno
{
    char apellido[50];
    char nombre[50];
    int dni;
    int legajo;
};

int Ingresar_Alumno (int &e)
{
    FILE *cho;
    Alumno vectoralumno[TOTAL];

    if (cho=fopen("cho.dat", "wb+"))
    {
            cout << "ingrese el nombre del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].nombre;

            cout << "ingrese el apellido del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].apellido;

            cout << "ingrese legajo del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].legajo;

            cout << "ingrese el DNI del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].dni;

        fwrite(vectoralumno,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,cho);

        }
    fclose(cho);
    e++;
}

void BuscarDNI(int dni, int &q)
{
    Alumno dchof;
    FILE *x;
    if(x=fopen("cho.dat","rb"))
{
  while ( true )
  {
    fread(&dchof,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,x);
    if( feof(x) )
      break;

    if(dni == (dchof.dni))
    {
        cout << "El alumno buscado es: " << endl;
        cout << "Nombre: " << dchof.nombre << endl;
        cout << "Apellido: " << dchof.apellido << endl;
        cout << "Legajo: " << dchof.legajo << endl;
        cout << "DNI: " << dchof.dni << endl;
        cout<< "Toque cualquier boton para volver al menu anterior" << endl;
        getch();
    }
  }
        if(dni!=dchof.dni)
        {
            cout<< "Error: DNI Incorrecto" << endl;
            cout<< "Toque cualquier boton para volver al menu anterior" << endl;
            getch();
        }
    }
    fclose(x);
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la declaración del objeto `Alumno`?

Comment: Es un struct

struct Alumno
{
    char apellido[50];
    char nombre[50];
    int dni;
    int legajo;
};

Comment: **No añadas información relevante para la pregunta en los comentarios**. En su lugar, edita la pregunta, los comentarios no tienen garantía de persistencia: podrían ser borrados en el futuro y si hay información importante en ellos la pregunta deja de tener sentido.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster perdón, soy nuevo acá, ahí edite la pregunta

Comment: ¿Cuál es el valor de `TOTAL`?

Comment: el valor de TOTAL es 1000

Comment: Edita la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int Ingresar_Alumno (int &e)
{
    FILE *cho;
    Alumno vectoralumno[TOTAL];

    if (cho=fopen("cho.dat", "wb+"))
    {
            cout << "ingrese el nombre del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].nombre; // 1

            cout << "ingrese el apellido del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].apellido; // 1

            cout << "ingrese legajo del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].legajo; // 1

            cout << "ingrese el DNI del alumno: ";
            cin >> vectoralumno[e].dni; // 1

        fwrite(vectoralumno,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,cho); // 2

        }
    fclose(cho);
    e++;
}
```

Estás actualizando los datos del registro `e` (comentario 1) y sin embargo **siempre** estás guardando lo que se encuentra en el primer registro del array (comentario 2).

Deberías dejar la escritura así:

```
fwrite(&vectoralumno[e],sizeof(struct Alumno),1,cho);
//     ^            ^^^ la posicion a guardar
//     para acceder a la posicion de memoria donde se encuentra el registro e
```

Por cierto, ya que programas en C++ podrías evitar el uso redundante de `struct`:

```
fwrite(&vectoralumno[e],sizeof(Alumno),1,cho);
```

Comment: Me borra el alumno anterior. Ingreso dos alumnos, busco el primer alumno y no me lo muestra

Comment: @SalvaCastro Cierto, no me fijé en los permisos de apertura del fichero, cambia `"wb+"` por `"ab+"` o incluso supongo que debería funcionar con `"ab"`

Comment: Cuando enseñan [tag:c++] ¿no enseñan `std::fstream`? O_o

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster se ve que no porque últimamente llegan muchas preguntas de C++ con `FILE*`

Comment: @eferion me sirvió cambiar "wb+" por "ab+"

Comment: @SalvaCastro piensa que C++ no es C sino que va mucho más allá. Intenta abandonar las costumbres de C.

Comment: En la ultima pregunta que hizo, yo le sugerí que cambiara a fstream, sin embargo _no cabe duda que es verdad que la costumbre es mas fuerte que el amor_

Comment: @JacoboCórdova lo se, no se puede usar ese argumento siempre...

Answer (score 3):

## Para que el vector?

El problema es que efectivamente no estabas escribiendo lo que estas guardando, sino solamente el primer miembro del vector...

Entonces para que usas un vector tan grande, lo que debes hacer es crear un solo Alumno y agregarlo al final del archivo.

## wb+ o ab+?

Pero el otro problema es que utilizas wb+ por lo tanto cada vez que fueras a agregar un usuario  ibas a borrar el contenido del archivo. en vez de ello sugiero el uso de ab+ para agregar al final del archivo el nuevo alumno (*si quieres crear un nuevo archivo cada vez que corres el programa debes establecer condiciones para hacer eso, por ejemplo al inicio del programa*)

## Podría quedar así

```
int Ingresar_Alumno (int &e)
{
    FILE *cho;
    //Alumno vectoralumno[TOTAL];
    Alumno fulano;
    if (cho=fopen("cho.dat", "ab+"))
    {
            cout << "ingrese el nombre del alumno: ";
            cin >> fulano.nombre;

            cout << "ingrese el apellido del alumno: ";
            cin >> fulano.apellido;

            cout << "ingrese legajo del alumno: ";
            cin >> fulano.legajo;

            cout << "ingrese el DNI del alumno: ";
            cin >> fulano.dni;

        fwrite(&fulano,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,cho);

        }
    fclose(cho);
    e++;
}

void BuscarDNI(int dni, int &q)
{
    Alumno dchof;
    FILE *x;
    if(x=fopen("cho.dat","rb"))
    {
        fseek(x,0,SEEK_SET);

        while ( fread(&dchof,sizeof(struct Alumno),1,x) )
        {

            if(dni == (dchof.dni))
            {
                Search:
                cout << "El alumno buscado es: " << endl;
                cout << "Nombre: " << dchof.nombre << endl;
                cout << "Apellido: " << dchof.apellido << endl;
                cout << "Legajo: " << dchof.legajo << endl;
                cout << "DNI: " << dchof.dni << endl;
                cout<< "Toque cualquier boton para volver al menu anterior" << endl;
                getch();
                // para que no imprima error aunque halla encontrado el usuario
                // retornas la funcion una vez encontrado
                fclose(x);
                return;
                
            }
        }
        // si logra salir del ciclo entonces quiere decir que no lo encontro
        cout<< "Error: DNI Incorrecto" << endl;
        cout<< "Toque cualquier boton para volver al menu anterior" << endl;
        getch();
        
    }
    fclose(x);
}
```

Comment: Gracias, me ahorraste una pregunta

Comment: Es lo que tiene responder a estas horas de la tarde... no caí en que el array interior de la función es innecesario

Comment: @JacoboCórdova si supiera hacerlo lo haria